# Failed API Certification

Tags: api, docusignapi

We are using the API to submit a form after a user signs a document, we add the integrator key and have performed 20+ transactions without errors. However, we continually fail.

We have submitted over 20 forms.

Awaiting approval.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking for help with or what the problem that you're seeing is.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's best to reach out to go-live@docusign.com to request assistance with the API Review process. When you reach out, please include your integration key, your Demo account ID and your Production account ID.

The [Go Live Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-troubleshooting) may help you investigate your cause of failure.